# How can I stop pillow from inserting a black frame into my animated gif

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm working on a program that takes an animated gif and return an asciified version of the gif as a different animated gif
example

```
asciify(foo.gif)
bar.gif has been created
```

After I make the gif and open it there is always a black frame at the start of the animation that makes it pretty annoying to watch on a loop.

I've tried setting the alpha channel of the created gif to 0 and only appending `ascii_image_gifs[1,-1]` to the output gif and I have run out of ideas.

demonstration:

original gif:
[trippy circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fovo.gif)

output gif:
[trippy ascii circles elongated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV6X1.gif)

EDIT: I've just had a breakthrough! This line in `gifify()` is the culprit: `save_as = Image.new('RGBA', (self._nw*3, self._nh*8), (0, 0, 0, 0))`

If I change it to `save_as = Image.new('RGBA', (self._nw*3, self._nh*8), 'white')`

the black frame become white, so my question become: How do I ignore the image created by `Image.new()` when saving/creating the output image?

below is the program, the relevant function is `gifify()`

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw


__author__ = 'Nikolas'


ASCII_SHADING_CHARS = ['M', 'W', 'N', 'Q', 'B', 'H', 'K', 'R', '#', 'E', 'D', 'F', 'X', 'O', 'A', 'P', 'G', 'U', 'S',
                       'V', 'Z', 'Y', 'C', 'L', 'T', 'J', '$', 'I', '*', ':', '.', ' ']  # from darkest to lightest 32
#ASCII_SHADING_CHARS = ASCII_SHADING_CHARS[::-1]


class Asciify:
    def __init__(self, img, new_width=500):
        self.width, self.height = img.size  # image.size returns a 2 tuple (width, height) in pixels
        self._nw = new_width
        self._nh = int(new_width * self.height / self.width)
        self.im = img

    def grayify_and_resize(self):
        """
        Split the GIF into individual frames. Resize and convert each frame to monochrome.
        :returns: a list of resized black&white Image objects
        """

        new_width = self._nw
        new_height = self._nh
        num_frames = self.im.n_frames  # number of frames in the .gif animation
        result_list = []
        for i in range(0, num_frames - 1):
            # convert to mode L (b&w); resize to new dimensions
            result_list.append(self.im.convert('L').resize((int(new_width), new_height)))
            self.im.seek(self.im.tell() + 1)  # move to the next frame in the gif animation

        return result_list

    def ascii_map(self, im_list, color_width=int(255 / len(ASCII_SHADING_CHARS))):
        """
        Maps an ascii shading character to a pixel of each frame of the GIF
        :param im_list: a list of black and white Image objects
        :param color_width: determines the color intensity of each pixel
        :returns: a list of each frame of the gif converted to ascii pixels
        """

        ascii_image_list = []  # unformatted ascii images; needs to be broken into proper rows and columns
        result_list = []  # ascii_image_list broken into proper rows and columns; how convinient
        for image in im_list:
            pixels = image.getdata()  # color data on every pixel per image
            append_list = []  # temporary list to append to ascii_image_list
            for pixel_value in pixels:
                index = int(pixel_value // color_width)
                if index >= len(ASCII_SHADING_CHARS):
                    append_list.append(ASCII_SHADING_CHARS[-1])
                else:
                    append_list.append(ASCII_SHADING_CHARS[index])  # 'replace' pixel with ascii char
            ascii_image_list.append(append_list)  # adds an element to ascii_image_list containing every pixel for image

        for ascii_image in ascii_image_list:
            ascii_string = "".join(ascii_image)
            result_list.append([ascii_string[index:index + self._nw]
                                for index in range(0, len(ascii_string), self._nw)])

        return result_list

    def gifify(self, ascii_image_list):
        """
        Return the ascii strings to .gif format for use in a traditional image viewer.
        :param ascii_image_list: A list of ascii 'pixel' images
        :returns: None
        """

        # 7 = nw*4, nh*10
        # 5 = nw*3, nh*8
        font = ImageFont.truetype('ascii.ttf', 5)  # set font and font size
        ascii_image_strings = ['\n'.join(image) for image in ascii_image_list]
        ascii_image_gifs = []
        for image in ascii_image_strings:
            #print(image)
            if image == ascii_image_strings[0]:
                continue
            temp_image = Image.new('RGBA', (self._nw*3, self._nh*8), (255,255,255,0))  # should be transparent, didn't work
            image_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(temp_image)
            image_draw.text((0, 0), image, font=font, fill='black')
            temp_image.resize((self._nw, self._nh))
            ascii_image_gifs.append(temp_image)
            if image == ascii_image_strings[-1]:
                save_as = Image.new('RGBA', (self._nw*3, self._nh*8), (0, 0, 0, 0))  # should also be transparent, didn't work
                save_as.save('temp.gif', save_all=True, append_images=ascii_image_gifs, loop=0, fps=24)
                save_as.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    im = Image.open("trippy.gif")
    asciify_im = Asciify(im, 110)
    gif_list = asciify_im.grayify_and_resize()
    ascii_images = asciify_im.ascii_map(gif_list)
    asciify_im.gifify(ascii_images)

    # Debugging ascii image creation #
    # outfile = open("outfile.txt", 'w')
    # for image in ascii_images:
    #    outfile.write("\n".join(image) + '\n\n')
```

Comment: Just providing the so-called "relevant function" isn't good enough. Please [edit] your question and make it a something that other can run to reproduce the problem and test their solutions to it.

Comment: ok, sorry, i've done that now. thank you

Comment: oh and if anyone does decide to run it you will want to make the new_width parameter pretty small(<150), and be sure the gif isnt too many (>25) frames or it will take forever.

Comment: Too late to check anywhere, but I seem to recall you need an alpha value of 127 for transparent in GIFs.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I just tried your suggestion and It did not work. Thanks though. It feels as this parameter `append_images=ascii_image_gifs` is appending that list of images to an existing all black image. This was happening to me a few days ago when i was accidentally appending my newly created gif onto the original gif, double the length and amount of frames. But I've browsed through the docs and can't find what is creating that black image.

Comment: The Pillow docs say that `resize()` returns a **copy** of the resized image, by the way.

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant to take that last bit at the bottom of `gifify()` out. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It feels as this parameter append_images=ascii_image_gifs is appending that list of images to an existing all black image.

You're 100% correct.

Calling `image.save("test.gif", append_images=images)`. Then `image` is the first frame and `images` is a list of all the extra/appended frames.

So instead, use `images[0]` as the first frame, and append the rest of the frames (`images[1:]`).

---

In your code `save_as` is the cause of the black frame. So instead remove that and only use `ascii_image_gifs`.

```
 ascii_image_gifs[0].save('temp.gif', save_all=True, append_images=ascii_image_gifs[1:], loop=0, fps=24)
```

It might be a bit convoluted, but that's how it works with PIL.

Comment: That's not too convoluted, it actually makes a lot of sense, I just hadn't thought of it lol. Thanks a lot!